# Reading binary file from the end

Tags: c++, file

Consider my code:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream izlazni_tok("Brojevi.dat", ios::binary);
    cout<<"Unesi 10 brojeva: ";
    double broj;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cin>>broj;
        izlazni_tok.write((char*)&broj, sizeof(broj));
    }
    cout<<"Obrnuti redoslijed: ";
    ifstream ulazni_tok("Brojevi.dat", ios::binary);
    ulazni_tok.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int duzina_datoteke(ulazni_tok.tellg());
    int broj_elemenata(duzina_datoteke/sizeof(double));
    for(int i=broj_elemenata-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        ulazni_tok.seekg(i*sizeof(double));
        ulazni_tok.read((char*)&broj, sizeof(broj));
        cout<<broj<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am a newbie in computer programming and i have been given a task to write a programm to write a binary file where u put 10 numbers into the file and then read them from the back of the file and display them when the programm runs. For some odd reason my programm doesn't display any numbers and i don't know why. Any help is welcome. :D

Comment: Thanks bro, it was the flush. Now everything works pefectly. :D

Comment: Close the question if everything was working fine

Answer (score 1):

Writing to a file is expensive, so file streams wait until they are forced to to actually commit the write to the file. Unless you `close` or `flush` `izlazni_tok`, odds are good what you wrote is sitting in a buffer in memory waiting for the buffer to fill up.

```
izlazni_tok.close(); // added to flush and close the output file
cout<<"Obrnuti redoslijed: ";
ifstream ulazni_tok("Brojevi.dat", ios::binary);
```

I also recommend adding some checks to make certain the files opened successfully and other checks to make sure that the reads and writes succeeded.